# HTML5 Canvas – Stop previous requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm using HTML Canvas. I want new frames to be requested only if the click function hasn't been fired again. Basically I want it to "stop" the previous recursiveness, I think

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(){

    [...]

    var animate = function() {
      if (the click event was NOT fired again) {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      }
    };
    animate();

});
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a global variable like `rafId` and in the line you invoke rAF make it like;

```
rafId = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

then when needed invoke [`cancelAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/cancelAnimationFrame) like `cancelAnimationFrame(rafId)`

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!